# How can i return variable "realImage" which is within onComplete method?

Tags: java, android

I've created an Asynctask in an activity and now i want to return the variable "realimage" to that Asynctask but i cant seem to access it...

```
public class PhotoUtils
{
public static Photo getImage(String id)
{
    unsplash.getPhoto(id, new Unsplash.OnPhotoLoadedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Photo photo)
        {
            Photo realImage=photo;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error)
        {

        }
    });

    return realImage; //This line shows error that cannot resolve symbol 
                        realImage
}
}
```

This is my Async Task which is in the other activity

```
public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Photo,Void,Photo>
{

    @Override
    protected Photo doInBackground(Photo... photos)
    {
            Intent intent=getIntent();

            Bundle bd=intent.getExtras();

            String getId = (String) bd.get("id");

            Photo finalPhoto=PhotoUtils.getImage(getId);

            return finalPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Photo finalPhoto) {
        tv1.setText(finalPhoto.getId());
        super.onPostExecute(finalPhoto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have `realImage` be a field in whatever class has this `getImage()` method.

Comment: if possible try adding  the whole code of the async task.

Answer (score 0):

First, looks like you don't even need an Asynctask. [Look at the example code](https://github.com/KeenenCharles/AndroidUnplash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kc/unsplashdemo/MainActivity.java)

Secondly, you can't return it like that.

`OnPhotoLoadedListener` is an asynchronous callback.

Just use the image as normal within `onComplete`.

If you needed to pass back the image to the calling method,   extract the callback to a parameter.

```
// this is void now 
public static void getImage(String id, Unsplash.OnPhotoLoadedListener listener) {
    unsplash.getPhoto(id, listener);
});
```

Call this as

```
PhotoUtils.getImage(id, new Unsplash.OnPhotoLoadedListener() {
    // Use image in here 
});
```

Which, if you look closely, all you did was replace normal usage of  `unsplash.getPhoto` with `PhotoUtils.getImage`, which may be want you want, but you could accomplish a similar approach with a singleton pattern around the `unsplash` instance variable. That way, you're not rewriting all of Unsplash API calls